# How to redirect domain to server's ip address (problem with <frameset> from namechap Mask)

Tags: web-hosting, ip-address, masking, namecheap, frameset

I have made a little website hosted on a server on a public network.
So I've got a domain on namecheap to reach it easily, problem is that if I mask it to render it within a frame, and this doesn't work the same way on mobile devices ([as described by them as well](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/314/2237/how-can-i-set-up-url-frame-for-my-domain)).
Here the masked version that gives me problems:
http://openais.live/
And here the original ip address, that works fine because of the meta-tags for responsiveness:
http://18.30.123.95:8080/

Comment: "it gives me problems" You don't say what the problems are.  It looks fine to me.  I am voting to close this as there isn't enough information to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want any type of redirect at all.  You want to assign your domain name to your website such that your domain name is used for your website.   You don't ever want your IP address to be visible to the users.  Redirects always change the URL that users see.

Namecheap has the instructions that you want to use here: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/434/2237/how-do-i-set-up-host-records-for-a-domain

You want to go the DNS setting and add two `A` records that point to your server's IP address.   You will want a record for the domain apex (no subdomain) and a second record for the `www` subdomain.  That will make it so that when users type in the domain name they are sent to your server.

Then you will need to configure your webserver to respond to requests for that domain name.   If your site is the only site on your server, your site is probably already configured as the default site and will show up.   Otherwise you will need to add `VirtualHost` directives for that domain name.

If you want to remove the `:8080` from your URL, you will need to change the server to port 80.   Port 80 is the only port that doesn't show up in a `HTTP` URL.